# Oculus Go Controller Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusgo

I have written a small script with the aim of getting my Oculus Go controller to move an object forwards, backwards, left and right. I have attached a screen grab. I've also set up the unity input manager to link to it. This does not seem to work however.

**Code screen shot**

[image: screen shot]

**Settings screen shot**

[image: Settings screen shot]

```
void Update()
{

    transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Oculus_GearVR_LThumbstickX") * Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 5);
    transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Oculus_GearVR_LThumbstickY") * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 5);

    transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Oculus_GearVR_LThumbstickX") * Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 5);
    transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Oculus_GearVR_LThumbstickY") * Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 5);

}
```

Comment: It's far better to include code as actual text rather a screenshot, for all sorts of reasons, but particularly to allow people to copy / paste it to run it themselves or edit it to include in an answer, and also to allow screenreaders to read it

Comment: Don't put image of your code, instead copy/paste the code in your question and format it, it will be easier to help you after :)